# Can I access Gnuplot "stats" command's sorted output?

Tags: sorting, gnuplot

According to Gnuplot stats help,

> ...
>    Data values are sorted to find the median and quartile boundaries.
>    ...

I am wondering if I can access this sorted data? For example, can I access the "10th smallest" value, not only the minimum value? (My viewers feel that absolute minimum may be an outlier and that 10th from the extreme may be more representative of the situation.)

On the one hand, some of this analysis would be easy in Perl, but then I haven't found a Perl module giving full-featured access to Gnuplot. So, I'm trying to do the analysis in Gnuplot.

Comment: You could use something like `min = system('sort -n data.dat | head -n +10 | tail -1')`.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph, the system call works and I can live with it. :-)

Comment: Fine :) I added this as an answer.

Comment: I discovered that this "nth smallest value" has a formal term in statistics: [order statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot access those sorted data values besides the values which are stored in variables. See `show variables all` after executing `stats` to see which are saved.

In your case you must use an external tool to achieve this. An easy variant would be to use some Unix command line tools which you call from gnuplot with the `system` function:

```
min = system('sort -n data.dat | head -n +10 | tail -1')
```